# Как склоняются слова пол пешня ударение в них?

Tags: склонение

Как склоняются слова *пол пешня* ударение в них?

Answer (score 1):

Слово **пешнЯ** склоняется так: в единственном числе - пешнЯ, пешнИ, пешнЕ, пешнЮ, пешнЁй (пешнЁю), пеншЕ; во множественном числе - пешнИ, пешнЕй, пешнЯм, пешнИ, пешнЯми, пешнЯх.

Слово **пол 1** 'нижнее покрытие, настил в помещении, в доме' склоняется так: ед.ч. - пол, пОла, пОлу,пол, пОлом, о пОле (на полУ); множ.ч. - полЫ, полОв, полАм, полЫ, полАми, полАх.

Слово **пол 2** 'совокупность признаков организма, определяющих роль особи в процессе оплодотворения' склоняется следующим образом: ед.ч. - пол, пОла, пОлу, пол,пОлом, пОле; множ.ч. - пОлы, полОв, полАм, пОлы, полАми, полАх.

Хочу обратить внимание на перенос ударения с существительного ПОЛ 1 на стоящий перед ним предлог, что является нормой: пол, п**О**ла, в (на) пол**У**;поклониться д**О** полу, уронить н**А** пол; ударить **О**б пол; спрятать п**О**д пол; хранить п**О**д полом; ходить п**О** полу; лежать на пол**У**; мн. пол**Ы**, -**О**в(настил)